# How to add leading 0 to int variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have a list which contains instanceNumber properties of type int I want to add leading 0 if its value is less than 10. i.e 01,02...09 after that 10,11,12 and goes on etc. I tried following code but it did not work

```
 var sidList = _sidRepository.GetAllList().Where(q=>q.IsDeleted==false).OrderByDescending(q=>q.Id).ToList();
            if (sidList.Count > 0)
            {
                sidList.Where(w => w.InstanceNumber<10).ToList().
                    ForEach(s => s.InstanceNumber = s.InstanceNumber.Value.ToString("D").Length + 2);
            }
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense. An int is just a number, and 01 is exactly the same number as 1. What might have leading zeroes, it the *string representation* of a number. Use `n.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')` to create a two-digit string with leading zeroes.

Comment: @Klaus or ToString with a format specifier, such as `"00"`

Comment: @AfaqRajput could you please edit the question with a desired output?

Comment: its working but as you can see that I store this value back to instance number which is int, and this particular code return string and if I convert this, again it remove the leading 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sidList = _sidRepository.GetAllList()
    .Where(q => !q.IsDeleted)
    .OrderByDescending(q => q.Id)
    .ToList();

if (sidList.Any())
{
    sidList
        .Where(w => w.InstanceNumber < 10)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(s => s.InstanceNumber = s.InstanceNumber.Value.ToString("00").Length + 2);
}
```

What I would suggest:

```
var sidList = _sidRepository.GetAllList()
    .Where(q => !q.IsDeleted)
    .OrderByDescending(q => q.Id);

if (sidList.Any())
    foreach (var item in sidList.Where(i => i.InstanceNumber < 10))
        item.InstanceNumber = item.InstanceNumber.Value.ToString("00").Length + 2;
```

My suggestion will return a `IEnumerable<item>` instead of a `List<item>`, but you can handle it afterwards with a `.ToList()` if you need it, but you'll benefit from performance, because you'll avoid ToList(ing) two times.

Comment: It does not work either gives the outpu 4 for all the element which has value less than 10

Comment: Have a look [here](https://imgur.com/wpt1rA6), I used the same string format, are you sure?